# Java For-Each Loop to Deal to multiple Hands

Tags: java, foreach

I'm trying to find a good way to 'deal' cards to 4 different hands.

```
         System.out.println("Deal to 4 Hands: "); 

         Hand hand1 = new Hand();
         Hand hand2 = new Hand();
         Hand hand3 = new Hand();
         Hand hand4 = new Hand();

         hand1.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
         hand2.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());             
         hand3.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
         hand4.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());

         hand1.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
         hand2.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());            
         hand3.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
         hand4.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());

         System.out.println("Cards left in deck: " + Deck.size());

         System.out.println("Player 1's Hand: \n" + hand1.getHand());
         System.out.println("Player 2's Hand: \n" + hand2.getHand());
         System.out.println("Player 3's Hand: \n" + hand3.getHand());
         System.out.println("Player 4's Hand: \n" + hand4.getHand());
```

Is there an easier way to deal to hands? For example using a For-Each loop?

I tried this: but it doesn't work. I haven't really used this type of loop very must...

```
         for(Hand card : hand1){
            System.out.println("Player 1's Hand: \n" + hand1);
         }
```

By the way, this deals 2 cards to 4 different hands, then prints each hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 System.out.println("Deal to 4 Hands: "); 

 Hand[] hands=new Hand[4];
 for(int i=0;i<hands.length;i++)
      hands[i]=new Hand();
 for(Hand hand:hands)
      hand.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
 for(Hand hand:hands)
      hand.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
 System.out.println("Cards left in deck: " + Deck.size());
 for(int i=0;i<hands.length;i++)
      System.out.println("Player "+i+"'s Hand: \n" + hands[i].getHand());
```

Comment: This is cool :) I think i'm going to use this but instead of 2 for-each loops, i'm going have 1 for-each loop inside a for-loop that loops twice. That way it will be easier to change if for some reason i need to deal say 8 cards. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

create an array!

```
Hand[] hands = new Hand[4];

// create Hand object within the array and deal a single card to each hand
for(int i = 0; i < hands.length; i++) {
    hands[i] = new Hand();
    hands[i].addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
}

// deal an additional card to each hand (use a nested loop for dealing additional cards, if necessary)
for(int i = 0; i < hands.length; i++) {
    hands[i].addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
}

System.out.println("Cards left in deck: " + Deck.size());

for(int i = 0; i < hands.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Player %d's hand: \n %s\n", i+1, hands[i]);
}
```

this array holds 4 separate Hand objects and allows you to perform operations on all of the hands by iterating through the array.

If you have four different named variables for each hand (hand1, hand2, etc) there is no simple way to perform operations on the objects they represent without explicitly using the variable name in the operation (hand1.dealSingleCard(), etc).

looping over an array is the way to go :)

Comment: This adds two cards to each hand at a time instead of giving one card to each hand, and then giving another to each hand. Depending on how Deck is implemented this may have different results.

Comment: @AlexLynch This is very cool and much nicer than my code :) Thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop isn't working because you placed one of your Hand objects as the item to iterate through. I'm not 100% familiar with all applications of this style of for loop, but in my experience with it, it is used to move through a list of objects. So you'd want to do something like this:

```java
     System.out.println("Deal to 4 Hands: "); 

     Hand hand1 = new Hand();
     Hand hand2 = new Hand();
     Hand hand3 = new Hand();
     Hand hand4 = new Hand();

     List<Hand> handList = new ArrayList<Hand>();
     handList.add(hand1);
     handList.add(hand2);
     handList.add(hand3);
     handList.add(hand4);

     for (Hand currHand : handList) {
         currHand.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
         currHand.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
     }
```

I realize I didn't use a for loop for adding to the list but I'm at work and it was easier to copy paste than to write from scratch.

Comment: You're adding two cards consecutively to the same hand.  I don't think that would fly at most casinos. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Store your hands in an array (or a List), and use two nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (Hand hand : hands) {
        hand.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the ForEach Loop on a class that implements Iterable

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work (not tested though):

```
Hand hands[] = new Hand[] {hand1, hand2, hand3, hand4};
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {               // deal 2 cards
    for (Hand currentHand: hands) {     // to each hand
         currentHand.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
    }
 }

for (int i=0; i<hands.length; i++)  {
     System.out.println("Player " + i + "'s Hand: \n" + hands[i].getHand());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for(int j=0; j<MAX_NUMBER_OF_DEALS_PER_PLAYER;j++)
{
  for(int i=0; i<MAX_HAND_SIZE;i++)
  {
    handsArray[i].addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
  }
}
```

?

You can then set number of deals to 2, for example, to replicate your example. And hand size will depend on the type of game you want to play.

Of course you need to initialize the array first, with something like:

```
Hand[] handsArray = new Hand[MAX_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS];
for(int i=0;i<MAX_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS;i++)
{
  handsArray[i] = new Hand();

}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

If you want to use a foreach loop, you can do of course what you posted:

```
for(Hand card : hand1){
  System.out.println("Player 1's Hand: \n" + card); //notice it needs to be card here, NOT hand1
}
```

Except note that you need to change hand1 to card here, to print each card in the hand. Otherwise you will just be printing the same value (hand1) for each card there is, so if you have 3 cards, it will print hand1's value 3 times.

Comment: Or yes, you can do what JB Nizet below says if you must use foreach loops, however I recommend first getting used to the other syntax first, as every foreach loop is a for loop, but not the other way around. It might be clearer when and how to use a foreach loop if you fully understand a for loop first.

Answer (score 0):

To use a for-each loop, you need an Iterable of some sort, either a Collection (i.e., List), or an array.  In this case your code could be greatly simplified:

```
private static final NUM_HANDS = 4;
System.out.println("Deal to 4 Hands: "); 
List<Hand> hands = new ArrayList<Hand>();
for(int i=0; i<NUM_HANDS) {
    hands.add(new Hand());
    hand.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
}
int handNum = 1;
for (Hand hand: hands) {
    hand.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
    System.out.println("Player " + handNum + "'s Hand: \n" + hand.getHand());
    handNum++;
}
System.out.println("Cards left in deck: " + Deck.size());
```